# URL Shortner Code is working fine on localhost but not on website

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have made a url shortner code in which user put the long url in text field and when user click on the submit button it insert the long url in DB and shows Short URL to the user, which is working perfectly on my localhost.

But when i uploaded it online its not working. Although the Data is inserting the DB online and it shows the Short URL but when i enter the url in the address bar it shows `The Site Cant Be Reached server DNS address could not be found.`. 
I think it is related to my .htaccess file.

This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?r=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?r=$1
```

This is my index.php file:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
if(isset($_GET['r']) || !empty($_GET['r']))
{
$url_id = $_GET['r'];

 $sql = "SELECT long_url FROM url_shortner WHERE url_id = '$url_id'";
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1)
  {
 $l_url = $row['long_url'];
  header('Location:' .$l_url);
  }
 else
  {
    header('Location: index2.php');
  }
 }?>
```

Comment: Is the server using Apache and is mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: yes its enabled @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Btw... You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not even escaping the user input

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Ok will change it to Prepared Statements

Comment: _"DNS address could not be found"_ does not sound like a htaccess-error. When you get that message, what URL do you see in the browser? Since you're redirecting the user, I would guess that it is the destination of your shortened URL that's the problem? What URL are you trying to redirecting to?

Comment: It shows my short url @MagnusEriksson Its not even redirecting to google

Comment: ...and what URL are you trying to redirecting to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129780/discussion-between-a-r-and-magnus-eriksson).

Comment: Is your long url working online?

Comment: @Abhishekgurjar Yes everything is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the chat room, there were some unexpected mistakes prior to deploying to your production server.

Despite of identifying and fixing the problem above, you still get 404 error which indicates a problem in the rewrite rule.

The rule below should work. You only need this one. No need for 2 rules.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\/?$ index.php?r=$1
```